# Advanced Unix Programming - Chapter 1 shell code error

Tags: c, unix

I noticed the following code of a simple shell program from the latest edition of Advanced Unix Programming did not run properly and compiled with a warning about comparing a pointer and integer in line 12:

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <sys/wait.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char    buf[MAXLINE];   /* from apue.h */
    pid_t   pid;
    int     status;

    printf("%% ");  /* print prompt (printf requires %% to print %) */
    while (fgets(buf, MAXLINE, stdin) != NULL) {
        if (buf[strlen(buf) - 1] == "\n")
            buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = 0; /* replace newline with null */

        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
            err_sys("fork error");
        } else if (pid == 0) {      /* child */
            execlp(buf, buf, (char *)0);
            err_ret("couldn't execute: %s", buf);
            exit(127);
        }

        /* parent */
        if ((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0)
            err_sys("waitpid error");
        printf("%% ");
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

The simple shell program would run, but then it would say "no such file or directory" for programs that I definitely had on the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the double quotes in the following line:

```
 if (buf[strlen(buf) - 1] == "\n")
```

It should have been like this:

```
 if (buf[strlen(buf) - 1] == '\n')
```

I believe interpreting the newline character as a string instead of a character created a situation where the statement was not true, and in turn creating a bad execlp() call.